# Import Error of IBM Watson Natural Language Understanding API

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson

I am now trying to extract keywords by using IBM Watson Natural Language Understanding API. I follow the instruction and have installed the watson_developer_cloud. However, I met an error when import the NaturalLanguageUnderstandingV1. Could you help me with it? Thank you!

```
  from watson_developer_cloud import NaturalLanguageUnderstandingV1
  Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-11-ab5aa6f014f4>", line 1, in <module>
  from watson_developer_cloud import NaturalLanguageUnderstandingV1

  File "C:\Users\yipin\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site- 
  packages\watson_developer_cloud\__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
  rom .speech_to_text_v1 import SpeechToTextV1

  File "C:\Users\yipin\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site- 
  packages\watson_developer_cloud\speech_to_text_v1.py", line 74, in <module>
from watson_developer_cloud.websocket import RecognizeCallback, RecognizeListener

   File "C:\Users\yipin\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\watson_developer_cloud\websocket\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
from .speech_to_text_websocket_listener import RecognizeListener

   File "C:\Users\yipin\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\watson_developer_cloud\websocket\speech_to_text_websocket_listener.py", line 21, in <module>
from twisted.internet import ssl, reactor

  File "C:\Users\yipin\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\ssl.py", line 59, in <module>
from OpenSSL import SSL

  File "C:\Users\yipin\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
from OpenSSL import crypto, SSL

  File "C:\Users\yipin\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\crypto.py", line 16, in <module>
from OpenSSL._util import (

  File "C:\Users\yipin\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\_util.py", line 6, in <module>
from cryptography.hazmat.bindings.openssl.binding import Binding

  File "C:\Users\yipin\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl\binding.py", line 13, in <module>
from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._openssl import ffi, lib

  ImportError: DLL load failed: The operating system cannot run %1.
```

Answer (score 0):

After reinstalling the watson-cloud-developer as an administrator. I solve the problem. It seems that if we do not run the pip install command as an administrator, then the package cannot be installed correctly.